# EWR international to international

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I am an EU-citizen, planning to fly Germany via USA (EWR) to Costa Rica on one tickets with a carry on. What are the rules in regards to immigration and security for such a connection?
My understanding is that US does not have concept of a transfer are requires to go via the immigration, is that correct?
Would your agree that 1h 50min in this case would not be enough for me to change?

Answer (score 8):

> My understanding is that US does not have concept of a transfer are requires to go via the immigration, is that correct?

Yes. You have to clear immigration, collect your bags, clear customs, drop off your bags after customs again, go to your departure terminal, go through security again and walk to your departure gate. The gate closes typically 15-20 minutes before departure.

> Would your agree that 1h 50min in this case would not be enough for me to change?

In most cases this will be fine. You can find recent immigration wait times here: https://awt.cbp.gov/ For security wait times, you can download a an app from the TSA https://www.tsa.gov/mobile .

You will need the correct paperwork to enter the US (Visa, ESTA etc.). They will not let you board in Germany otherwise.

A lot of the actual time depends on your details. With Global Entry, TSAPreCheck a nd no checked luggage I've made 25 minute connection in Newark.

It's not a bad idea to familiarize yourself with the layout of the airport. I assuming this is a United or Lufthansa ticket. If you are arriving with Lufthansa you need to transfer from Terminal B to Terminal C (probably using the air train). If you arrive on United, you can stay in Terminal C.

If you happen to miss the connection through no fault of your own, the airline will rebook you on the next available flight, which might be the next day and provides some assistance. It's another good idea to document your progress step by step just in case the airline challenges "no fault of your own".

Comment: At LAX they had a dedicated immigration line for people with tighter onward connections. Also, on my last flight in, the first bags to come off the belt, after those of premium passengers, I noticed had other final destinations tagged on them than LAX.

Answer (score 7):

The general rule in the US is indeed that anyone needs to enter the US and thus go through immigration and customs even if they have an international connection.

There are apparently a few exceptions with specific ITI programmes for specific airlines (or even flights) at some airports, but details are scarce, and as far as I know, no such program exists at EWR.

So the most likely situation is indeed that (in your case, without checked luggage) you will have to go through immigration, customs, find your way to departures, security, and on to your gate.

A few years ago, most people would have said doing this is less than 2 hours would be madness as you could spend more time than that just queuing for passport control (especially for non U.S. citizens/residents).

Apparently nowadays with kiosks and other automated processes this is actually quite doable (even more so without checked luggage).

Also remember that (as your have both flights on a single ticket) if it doesn’t go as planned, it’s the airline‘s responsibility to rebook you, so, as long as there are other flights later that day, you’re not travelling on a very busy day, and you don’t absolutely need to arrive on time (which would be a very bad idea anyway, there are lots of other reasons that just long queues at passport control for arriving later or much later than planned), you don’t have much to worry about. You may get there later than planned, but you’ll get there.

Comment: @Nina Because you're flying on a single ticket, the airline is confident that you'll make the connection. It's more trouble and cost for them if the connection fails.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Granted, I don't think Minimum Connection Time takes into account citizenship, whether you have Global Entry or PreCheck, time of day, etc.

Comment: @reirab I would say MCT should take into account the "reasonable worst case scenario" (i.e. non US-citizen/resident, without Global Entry, Nexus or Sentri, without PreCheck, longer than average queue at both immigration and security, small incoming delay). Of course it can't take into account one being sent to secondary for an hour-long interview or your checked luggage being delayed or lost, but it should not be just a best case for Global Entry-enrolled US citizens on quiet days, otherwise it's completely useless.